link_to in rails with method :delete still performs GET request "Rails 7.1.3.2"
I wanted to run a delete method from the device authentication gem
I tried both
    <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>

and
    <%= link_to "Logout2", destroy_auth_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

but they both end up using GET method
this is the rails documentation for Rails 7.1.3.2: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#deleting-an-article

almost the same stack overflow question but it doesn't answer my problem: Rails 7 - link_to with method :delete still performs GET request

What is destroy_auth_user_session_path? Generally speaking this route would not have the word destroy in it instead it would just be auth_user_session_path and would require a resource (e.g. @article as shown in the example). This would be sent with the pseudo HTTP verb DELETE (that's what turbo_method: :delete is for). Can you post the relevant portions of your routes file so we can see what is going on?

This is the perennial unanswerable Rails question with hundreds of duplicates. Using links to send non get requests relies on Turbo in Rails 7 which provides a fill in for the old functionality of Rails UJS. data-turbo-method is the correct attribute. However there are so many reasons why this can break - the needed JS assets are not loaded on the page, script errors etc. The feature is largely retained just for legacy apps. It's recommended that you use button_to instead which doesn't come with these problems.

@engineersmnky if you have devise_for :user in your routes Devise will actually generate a helper named destroy_user_session_path which breaks with convention. It's also a singular route since it's implied that the user can only have one session.

If you still want to use link_to you need to start debugging why the turbo event handler isn't working. Read the JavaScript in Rails guide and learn how to debug JavaScript in the browser.

Please replace the screenshots of code with the actual textual code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

you need to add this line, in order to work data-turbo
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails" # app/javascript.js

make sure you have already gem install
gem 'turbo-rails'

and obviously pin this in importmap.rb
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js

then

data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: "Are you sure?" }

will work as you expected

You need to use button_to helper, for example
<%= button_to 'Delete', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>

can I not use link_to ???

instead of link_to you should use button_to

@engineersmnky author asked about using link_to for calling destroy action, I had answered that calling destroy action should be performed with button_to helper instead, what is wrong?
